# Maven tests fail when running with Github Action

Tags: spring, postgresql, junit, github-actions, testcontainers

I am using PostgreSQL's testcontainers for my tests and trying to create a workflow for my test runs. The tests pass in my local environment even if I running in IDE or with `mvn test` command.

The errors I am getting about the connection of PostgreSQL. The errors log from GitHub action output:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:319) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    ... 101 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    ... 115 common frames omitted
```

Here are my test properties and pom:

application-test.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

bootstrap-test.properties

```
embedded.postgresql.enabled=true
embedded.postgresql.dockerImage=postgres:latest
embedded.postgresql.user=postgres
embedded.postgresql.password=root
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>

     .

     .

     .


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Github Action:

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 17
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '17'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn test
```

Comment: Can you please also share the actual test?